# VoiceOver fails to focus an input (or button) when navigating row wise inside a table

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, focus, wai-aria, voiceover

Reproduction of the bug: https://codepen.io/rybadour/pen/xMwXyv

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th><input type="checkbox" aria-label="header checkbox" /></th>
      <th>Header 1</th>
      <th>Header 2</th>
      <th><button>All Action</button></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><div><input type="checkbox" aria-label="row checkbox"/></div></td>
      <td>foobar</td>
      <td>foobar</td>
      <td><div><button>Action</button></div></td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

In the above code when navigating with VoiceOver you'll find that the checkbox in the  (first row) will not be focused (browser active element, no focus ring) when moving from the header checkbox down. However, VoiceOver will read the checkbox details correctly and visually shows that it is selected by VoiceOver.

It seems that if the focusable element is nested inside another element VoiceOver fails to focus it correctly even though the element is read correctly.

Anyone know how I can fix this issue without removing the surrounding div element?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> the checkbox in the <tr> will not be focused

Can you clarify?  There are two checkboxes in your table and they are both contained in a <tr>.  One is in the <thead> and one is in the <tbody>.  I'm assuming you're talking about the latter since you talk about moving down from the header but I wanted to be clear.

Your codepen sample seems to work ok with VoiceOver on iOS.  You're having trouble with VoiceOver on the Mac?  It also works ok with NVDA on Firefox.

Even though this is probably a simplified example, note that if my screen reader focus is on the 2nd row and in the 2nd column (the "foobar" cell) and I use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>left</kbd> to move to the first cell, the column's header will be read first, which is "header checkbox", and then the cell's contents will be read, which is "row checkbox", so the screen reader user will hear "*header checkbox, row checkbox*".

> the checkbox in the <tr> will not be focused...[but] VoiceOver...visually shows that it is selected

Another clarification.  When you say the checkbox "will not be focused", are you talking about the keyboard focus, such as an outline that is typically drawn around the active element when you <kbd>tab</kbd> to it?  And then when you say VO visually shows it's selected, do you mean the VoiceOver "focus", normally a thick black outline?

What does it sound like when you tab through the checkboxes?

Comment: Edited my description to be more clear. The checkbox and button in the row are wrapped in a div which is causing the problem. If I move from the header element down it fails to make the browser focus the element. The major consequence of this is that the user will hear that they are on a new checkbox but all keyboard controls are actually being sent to the header one.